TOC has pagenumbering with pagestyle{empty}
I am writing a thesis and it starts with titlepage stuff, followed by a table of contents, followed by the conten of the thesis. My goal is to start the page numbering from the content onwards by arabic numbering, all previous pages should not display a pagenumberung.
For the pdf version, to seperate titlepage stuff from content, I want to use roman numbering (without display).
My code looks as follows:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrbook}
\raggedbottom

\input{header}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\input{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\input{content}

\end{document}

However, the TOC page displays the page number despite the fact that I am using empty pagestyle.
Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Chapter-level entries tend to be accompanied by implicit \thispagestyle{plain} directives, overriding any existing \pagestyle{empty} settings. In case the ToC occupies just one page, have you tried issueing the instruction \thispagestyle{empty} immediately after \tableofcontents?

BTW: Why aren't you using \frontmatter and \mainmatter? Note also, that roman numbering should usually also include the title page(s).

Without minimal working example I guess, you are searching something like \AfterTOCHead{\thispagestyle{empty}}. Or maybe \renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{empty} for your frontmatter and \renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{plain} for the mainmatter. See the KOMA-Script manual for more information.

Off-topic: Usually I would not recommend to use \raggedbottom. In most cases there are better solutions for the problems usually “solved” using \raggedbottom, e.g., allow floats to float.

I have already made one assumption.But it depends on why you are using \raggedbottom. So if you are interested, ask a new question with a suitable minimal working example.

Without a minimal working example and therefore without knowing the code of files header.tex and content.tex of your example, I would suggest to use \frontmatter and \mainmatter instead of manually changing the page numbering. Additionally you need to know, that chapter starting pages use their own pagestyle and table of contents, list of figures etc. are also chapters. With KOMA-Script classes the pagestyle used for those chapter starting pages is not hard-coded but given by \chapterpagestyle. So you can redefine it in \frontmatter and in \mainmatter:
\usepackage{mwe}% for dummy content in a MWE

\AddToHook{cmd/frontmatter/after}{%
  \pagestyle{empty}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}% also for chapter starting pages
}
\AddToHook{cmd/mainmatter/after}{%
  \pagestyle{headings}% reset the default of scrbook
  \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}% reset the default of scrbook
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{Demonstration of pagestyle \texttt{empty} in the frontmatter}
\author{Cabohah}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument
\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument\blinddocument
\end{document}

Now, the table of contents would be:

but the first chapter starts with:

Note: Using \frontmatter already before the title pages is intended. The title pages are not cover pages, but the in-book title pages. These are counted. Moreover this still works without “destination with same identified” when using hyperref.
For more information about \AddToHook see LaTeX news 34 and LaTeX's hook management. For information about \chapterpagestyle, \frontmatter and \mainmatter see the KOMA-Script user manuals.
